# Why are multiple 3D Object makings sound even when not pressing on any of them?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-development

Me and my friend are trying to do a piano app for mobile phones. Our piano keyboard "keys" are 16 3D Objects next to each other. The problem is that when I press pretty much anywhere on the screen, it plays all of the audioclips that I have put on the 3D Objects all at once. I have tried multiple scripts, but all of them have the same problem or a different.
Here is my current script that im using:

PS. I am still a total noob in Unity and C# so all help is welcome. :)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Audio;


[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
public class key1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    AudioSource AudioSource;
    Touch theTouch;
    
    void Start()
    {
        AudioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }
    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            theTouch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            if (theTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                
               AudioSource.Play();

            }
           if (theTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
           {

               AudioSource.Stop();
            }
           if (theTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            {
               AudioSource.Stop();
            }
           if (theTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Canceled)
            {
               AudioSource.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because i would guess all keys have this and your script only checks that there is a touch. Its not checking on what or where. And the fact the script is on all keys means it plays all notes

Comment: @BugFinder Thanks for the reply. Yes, every key has the same script (the only change is the public class). Do you know how I can make my script detect where the player is tapping the screen and make the keys play their sound only when they are the one being tapped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you might not need an AudioSource on every "key". It is enough with one if you only want to play the sounds. However, if you want 3D sound where the key on the left is on your left speaker, then you need an AudioSource on every key.

To know which key to play, you can do a simple ray-cast from the screen position (where you clicked) to the 3D world. You only need to do one ray-cast, so don't do it in your key-scripts. Move it to a separate script together with the AudioSource if you are satisfied without 3D sound.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Assertions;

public class Piano : MonoBehaviour
{
    AudioSource audioSource;

    private void Awake()
    {
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        Assert.IsNotNull(audioSource);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            // The user has clicked (or touched) on the screen. Convert it to a position in the 3D world:
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                // The user has clicked on a Collider. Does it have a Key script on it?
                Key key = hit.collider.GetComponent<Key>();
                if(key != null)
                {
                    // The user clicked on a key. Play the sound (without interrupting previous sounds).
                    audioSource.PlayOneShot(key.clip);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The script on the keys can then be as simple as:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Key : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioClip clip;
}
```

---

If you want 3D sound you move the AudioSource to the keys (one AudioSource on every key). The piano code would then be something like:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Piano : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            // The user has clicked (or touched) on the screen. Convert it to a position in the 3D world:
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                // The user has clicked on a Collider. Does it have a Key script on it?
                Key key = hit.collider.GetComponent<Key>();
                if(key != null)
                {
                    key.Play();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the key script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Assertions;

public class Key : MonoBehaviour
{
    // You could also simply add the sound to the audioSource from the editor.
    public AudioClip clip;
    AudioSource audioSource;

    private void Awake()
    {
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        Assert.IsNotNull(audioSource);
    }

    public void Play()
    {
        audioSource.PlayOneShot(clip);
    }
}
```

---

And finally, a touch version with 3D sound. It is very similar to previous examples, but we now also keep track of how long the keys are down.

As before we use a ray-cast to get the key the user is pressing on. But we also store the fingerId, so we know which finger it was and can release the right key when that finger is released.

The sound clip is in this example stored together with the AudioSource.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Piano : MonoBehaviour
{
    Key[] allKnownKeys;

    private void Awake()
    {
        allKnownKeys = FindObjectsOfType<Key>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
        {
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Canceled)
            {
                // Get the key using the fingerID (the finger that pressed down the key)
                Key key = GetKey(touch.fingerId);
                // Was it a key that was released?
                if(key != null)
                    key.Stop();
            }
            else if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                // New touch on the screen. Convert it to a position in the 3D world:
                Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);
                RaycastHit hit;
                if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
                {
                    // The user has touched a Collider. Does it have a Key script on it?
                    Key key = hit.collider.GetComponent<Key>();
                    if (key != null)
                    {
                        key.Play(touch.fingerId);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the key which is already "down" (playing).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fingerId"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private Key GetKey(int fingerId)
    {
        foreach (Key key in allKnownKeys)
            if (key.FingerId == fingerId)
                return key;
        return null;        
    }
}
```

And the key script for the touch version:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Assertions;

public class Key : MonoBehaviour
{
    AudioSource audioSource;

    private void Awake()
    {
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        Assert.IsNotNull(audioSource);
        FingerId = -1;
    }

    public void Play(int fingerId)
    {
        if (FingerId >= 0)
            return; // The key is already "down"
        FingerId = fingerId;
        audioSource.Play();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        FingerId = -1;
        audioSource.Stop();
    }

    public int FingerId { get; protected set; }
}
```

Comment: Of course, for the ray-cast to work every key need a Collider component.

Comment: Note though that OP uses **touches**, not the mouse so you might want to take that into account .. if using the `Stop` it also makes sense to use a source for each key

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it has definitely helped me but I still have one question. Where do I put the "Piano" script? I have tried it on the Canvas and MainCamera but nothing seems to work.

Comment: You can put the "Piano" module on any game object in your scene as long as it isn't disabled. Which of the three examples are you trying?

Comment: I'm using the last one with touch controls.

Comment: OK, it uses touch so you need to debug it with Unity Remote. Could that be the reason? If you are unsure, try the second (3D sound) example - it works with touch and mouse.

Comment: I don't know why, but Unity Remote doesn't work form me. I can open it and it shows the game on the screen when I hit play in Unity, but nothing happens when I touch the screen. So to test my game, I have been using "Build and Run" to play it on my phone. There everything (except the keys) work fine. I tried the second example and nothing has changed (keys don't work, everything else works).

Comment: Add the following in the beginning of the foreach touch-loop: `code`Debug.Log("Touch " + touch.phase + " for finger " + touch.fingerId.ToString());`code`. We can then check if the touch is working or not. If you get output in the Console, check that you have Sphere or Box Colliders on each Key (for the ray-cast to hit). If you don't get any output in the Console there is something wrong with the touch/remote settings, try the Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) approach.

Comment: Thanks for still helping me! I put the line of code in the foreach loop and using Unity Remote I got output in the console (it said "Touch Stationary/ Moved/ Ended for Finger 0"). I have a 3D Box Collider component on every Key. Still no sound. I even used the Windows Volume Mixer to see, if Unity is outputting audio and I just don't hear it. It didn't show any audio coming from my Unity project.

Comment: Try and play a sound in the Awake() method, just to check that there isn't something else. Do something like: `code`Awake(){audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();audioSource.Play();}`code`. If you don't hear anything when the game starts, it could be: 1. You have forgotten to add a clip to the AudioSource. 2. The AudioSource has some wrong settings like mute enabled. 3. There isn't any Audio Listener (usually on the Camera to get good 3D sound).

Comment: I can hear the sound with the Awake method when the game turns on, but after that its the same as before. Is it possible to change the sound from 3D to 2D? Would that change anything?

Comment: I don't know how important it is but when I touch a Key the console gives me an error: "Error Unity NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object at Piano.Update () [0x000b1] in C:\Users\...Piano.cs:29."

Comment: Great, then we know that the error is on line 29 in the Piano code. On my side it would be the line `code`"if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))"`code`. Is it the same line on your side? If it is it might be that ray is null, I wonder why...

Comment: For me the code on line 29 reads `code` Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position); `code` The line "if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))" is on line 31 for me.

Comment: The line `code`Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay`code` assumes that you have a normal Camera tagged [MainCamera](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-main.html). Have you a different tag? If unsure, you can always add a public field like `code`public Camera ourCamera;`code` at the top of the Piano class (and then of course drag your Camera into that field in the Editor).

Comment: You then of course also have to change line 29 to `code`Ray ray = ourCamera.ScreenPointToRay(...`code`.

Comment: My Camera is named MainCamera. Even after I put the "public Camera Camera;" public field in the script and dragged the MainCamera in it in the editor the error still shows up exactly the same.

Comment: 1. Did you remember to use the new field "ourCamera" instead of "Camera.main"? 2. If it is not the camera that is null then it must be the "touch", and that shouldn't be null if you have the same code as above. 3. If you know how to use the Debugger, this is unnecessary, but otherwise add some debug-calls just before line 29, like `code`Debug.Log("Camera: " + ourCamera.name );`code` and `code`Debug.Log("Touch: " + touch.ToString() );`code` and so on...

Comment: Great, after doing the changes the error doesn't come up anymore. But I still can't hear any sound.

Comment: Great. Try now and add some more `code`Debug.Log();`code` calls and check what the ray-cast returned and if we reach the `code`audioSource.Play();`code` call. Here are some helpful links about ray-casting [Physics.Raycase](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) and [Raycasting in Unity](https://www.codinblack.com/raycasting-in-unity3d/)

Comment: If you add a `code`Debug.Log('xxx');`code` line (where xxx is some unique text) after each line in the code you should quickly find how far you get. Of course, I would personally recommend starting using the debugger - it makes life soo much easier.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! After debugging and a lot of googling (and I mean a lot) my program finally works! I'm still not exactly sure what I did, but still. Thank you again for answering all my questions!